# Hibernate-Envers supported in Reactive Panache?

Tags: hibernate, quarkus

Does the Hibernate Envers extension support the Reactive ORM clients?

I didn't see any mention at https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-envers

When I tried to include the extension along with all the reactive JDBC drivers like `pg-client` and `reactive-panache` etc.. I get a strange error.

```
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.SyntheticBeansProcessor#initRuntime threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A synthetic bean with identifier 9c40b3d5cbb6ee6bb4cf2cb7bab0a1fda6694fe5 is already registered: SYNTHETIC bean [types=[org.hibernate.SessionFactory, jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@jakarta.enterprise.inject.Default, @Any], target=n/a]
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.addSyntheticBean(BeanDeployment.java:1410)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment$BeanRegistrationContextImpl.accept(BeanDeployment.java:1693)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment$BeanRegistrationContextImpl.accept(BeanDeployment.java:1676)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanConfigurator.done(BeanConfigurator.java:96)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.SyntheticBeansProcessor.configureSyntheticBean(SyntheticBeansProcessor.java:92)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.SyntheticBeansProcessor.initRuntime(SyntheticBeansProcessor.java:56)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:864)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

Removing all the reactive extensions and using the standard `blocking` extensions make the code compile.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there's no integration between Envers and Hibernate Reactive.

See https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/issues/394